# JSON Parser error. Value This of type

Tags: java, android, json

Im completely new to android development, hence my question might be badly formatted.

I have the following in MainActivity.java:

```
package learn2crack.listview;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;



import learn2crack.listview.library.JSONParser;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView list;
    TextView name;
    TextView address;
    TextView status;
    Button Btngetdata;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    //URL to get JSON Array
    private static String url = "http://portal.ontimebemanning.no/api/json/clients/";

    //JSON Node Names 
    private static final String TAG_CLIENTS = "clients";
    private static final String JSON_NAME = "firm";
    private static final String JSON_ADDRESS = "address";
    private static final String JSON_STATUS = "status";

    JSONArray android = null;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();



        Btngetdata = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getdata);
        Btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 new JSONParse().execute();


            }
        });


    }



    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
         private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
             name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
             address = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.address);
             status = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.status);
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();



        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // Getting JSON from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            return json;
        }
         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
             pDialog.dismiss();
             try {
                    // Getting JSON Array from URL

                    android = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CLIENTS);
                    for(int i = 0; i < android.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                    String name = c.getString(JSON_NAME);
                    String address = c.getString(JSON_ADDRESS);
                    String status = c.getString(JSON_STATUS);




                    // Adding value HashMap key => value


                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put(JSON_NAME, name);
                    map.put(JSON_ADDRESS, address);
                    map.put(JSON_STATUS, status);

                    oslist.add(map);
                    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);





                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, oslist,
                            R.layout.list_v,
                            new String[] { JSON_NAME,JSON_ADDRESS, JSON_STATUS }, new int[] {
                                    R.id.name,R.id.address, R.id.status});

                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                int position, long id) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at "+oslist.get(+position).get("name"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });

                    }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


         }
    }

}
```

And in JSONParser.java:

```
    package learn2crack.listview;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;



    import learn2crack.listview.library.JSONParser;



    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        ListView list;
        TextView name;
        TextView address;
        TextView status;
        Button Btngetdata;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        //URL to get JSON Array
        private static String url = "HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY_PURPOSES";

        //JSON Node Names 
        private static final String TAG_CLIENTS = "clients";
        private static final String JSON_NAME = "firm";
        private static final String JSON_ADDRESS = "address";
        private static final String JSON_STATUS = "status";
        package learn2crack.listview.library;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}

        JSONArray android = null;




        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();



            Btngetdata = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getdata);
            Btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                     new JSONParse().execute();


                }
            });


        }



        private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
             private ProgressDialog pDialog;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                 name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
                 address = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.address);
                 status = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.status);
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();



            }

            @Override
            protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

                // Getting JSON from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
                return json;
            }
             @Override
             protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
                 pDialog.dismiss();
                 try {
                        // Getting JSON Array from URL

                        android = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CLIENTS);
                        for(int i = 0; i < android.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                        String name = c.getString(JSON_NAME);
                        String address = c.getString(JSON_ADDRESS);
                        String status = c.getString(JSON_STATUS);




                        // Adding value HashMap key => value


                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        map.put(JSON_NAME, name);
                        map.put(JSON_ADDRESS, address);
                        map.put(JSON_STATUS, status);

                        oslist.add(map);
                        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);





                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, oslist,
                                R.layout.list_v,
                                new String[] { JSON_NAME,JSON_ADDRESS, JSON_STATUS }, new int[] {
                                        R.id.name,R.id.address, R.id.status});

                        list.setAdapter(adapter);
                        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                    int position, long id) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at "+oslist.get(+position).get("name"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        });

                        }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


             }
        }

    }
```

When I debug my application it stops with the following error:

Error parsing data org.json.jsonException: Value This of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

I've tried googling it without any luck so far.

The data returned by the url should be valid json.
Example of the result from the URL:

```
{"database":"clients","clients":[{"id":"1","firm":"Ringnes NT","address":"Postboks 7152 Majorstua","address2":"CostCenter:222"}]}
```

So, obviously, my question would be. Why am I getting this error returned.
Secondly, to help me figure out this stuff for myself, is there anyway I can log the JSON-result raw data to see what my application is recieving?

This is the LogCat output:
[image]

And in my MainActivity-window, it breaks at this line:
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: "Error parsing data org.json.jsonException: Value This of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject" this error occur when you try to convert the string into jsonobject and the string is not in a json format.....JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url); for sure, the url string does validate the json format...

Comment: inside getJSONFromUrl() method defination...first print method return... i.e. jObj.toString(); and check that string is it valid json or not? you can use jsonlint.com

Comment: The string validates as valid json, so thats not where the problem lies. The code breaks on the following line: android = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CLIENTS);

Comment: ok first tell me ....the exception occur at which line...? and what was that statement? the line must be where the jsonobject is created ..

Comment: @AngadTiwari the breakpoint is at android = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CLIENTS); I updated my questions with printscreens of it.

Comment: do one thing....print the "json" string and "android" string after that line...Log.i("jsontest",json.toString());Log.i("jsontest",android.toString()); and send me the result

Comment: Issue is getting raised from `getJSONFromUrl()`!